# asp.net core delete appsettings.json for different environments after publish/deploy

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Web api is deployed in an on-premise web server. I have setup the release pipeline through azure devops. Now looking for a way to remove appsettings.env.json after deployment is complete

such that:

appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Staging.json are removed from the target directory of the production environment after the app is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops).

The UI interface operation is as follows, add a Delete files from task to the Deployment group job.
[image]

And then add the files you want to delete, that is, the paths specified by appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Staging.json.

[image]

Save and run when you are done.

Comment: Can you delete files now?
If not, can you reverse your progress with us? Or you have found other ways to accomplish this task, if so, can you share the solution with us?

Comment: Where in the pipeline should this be called? I tried before and after the *build* step, but my appsettings.Development.json is still there. This is my command
`- task: DeleteFiles@1
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 
    Contents: 'appsettings.Development.json'`

Comment: @JulieXu-MSFT Hi there, with XML file transformation like the web.config, after transformation all variations of the config are removed and only web.config is left. that does not seem to be the case with appsettings.json? Is there a way for the framework to remove the unnecessary appsettings.env.,json out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have specified the Environment key in the web.config file, other files will not be included.
`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
}
...`
```

So it would be fine even if you will not delete the other files.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. One usually wants to remove development appsettings because they may contain private information, so not deleting them is not fine.